# Why can't I reassign elements to an array that was deallocated with delete []?

Tags: c++, new-operator, delete-operator

I'm investigating the delete [] operator, and I was wondering this - Why can't I make another array elements assignment on that same pointer that I deleted earlier using the 'delete []' operator?

Here is what I was doing:

```
int *a = new int[n];
cout << "Enter array elements:" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    cin >> a[i];

cout << "a address: " << &a << " points to: " << a << endl;
cout << "a: "; printArray(a,n);

delete [] a; cout << "deletes a" << endl;

cout << "Enter new a elements:" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    cin >> a[i];

cout << "a address: " << &a << " points to: " << a << endl;
cout << "a: "; printArray(a,n);
```

And the output is:

```
Enter array elements: 1 1 1
a address: 0025FAAC points to: 001172C8
a: 1 1 1
deletes a
Enter new a elements: 2 2 2
a address: 0025FAAC points to: 001172C8
a: -572662307 -572662307 -572662307
```

What is the reason for this?

Comment: If you wanted to assign to it again, why did you `delete` it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing this:

```
int * x = new int[3];
x[0] = 1;
x[2] = 2;

delete [] x;

x[0] = 3; // <-- Undefined Behavior!
```

Dereferencing a pointer that points to memory that you've deleted is **undefined behavior**.

Continuing to use that pointer will cause your program to behave in undefined ways including possibly crashing or having any number of other issues.

That being said, `x` is just a variable. So we can keep using the variable. We just can't continue to use **what it pointed to**. So let's look at some code to explain this:

```
int * x = new int[3];
x[0] = 1;
x[2] = 2;

delete [] x;
x = NULL;

x = new int[4];
x[3] = 4; // <-- This is fine.
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not reallocating the array:

```
int *a = new int[n];
...
cin >> a[i]
...
delete [] a;
...
// here you must allocate a new array
...
cin >> a[i];
```

Once you delete the array, memory on heap that was available to is no longer available, you are storing data with your second `cin` where you shouldn't. In your example this address `0x001172C8` becomes invalid after the delete. Allocating a new array should provide you a new address (usually).

Comment: Which means I could not use the 'a' identifier again to create a new array, am I correct? What can I do with its current state?

Comment: You can reuse the identifier, it's a pointer, you can reassign it to another address.

Answer (score 2):

According the draft standard,

> 18.6.1.2/9
>
> `void operator delete[](void* ptr) noexcept;`
>
> Effects: The deallocation function (3.7.4.2) called by the array form of a delete-expression to render the value of `ptr` invalid.

Hence, executing

```
delete [] a;
```

make `a` invalid, according to the standard. If a certain platform allows `a` to be used after that without crashing or other strange behavior is only a matter of luck.